# How to send a data to an Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal-dialog

I've a `Foreach` in a table, I want to open a modal when user click on a cell and show the object of the cell in a `partialView` `modal`.

The Foreach:

```
     @foreach (PedidoModel pedido in @Model.Entidades)
                {
                    <tr title="Clique para exibir detalhes" style="cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td>@pedido.Pessoa.Nome</td>
                        <td>@pedido.DataEntrega</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>R$ @pedido.ValorTotal</td>
                        <td>@pedido.Endereco</td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="label label-success">@pedido.Status</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

I try to put the `partialView` inside `foreach` but always open same content, like this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Areas/Unidade/Views/Pedidos/_DetalhePedido.cshtml",pedido)
```

I use this `Jquery` code to open and close `modal`

```
   $("#myModal").on("show", function () {
        $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    }).on("hidden", function () {
        $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
    });
```

I can't found a solution to this, if someone could help me, I'll be really grateful.

Comment: Where is the Html.RenderPartial on your code?

Comment: I'm using only @Html.Partial, this code was on the end of the page, befode <script> tag, but i place insede my foreach, so I can pass the right object to the PartialView, but after render partialview for first time the content will not change, only will dismiss the modal and re-open with same content. I looking for a good solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about using Ajax to load the modal Async?

For example, put a div which will contain the modal, say id="ModalContainer"
Then with Ajax, you can load the view which will actually contain the modal and insert it into the DOM with Jquery and show the modal.

Then in the cell just set an onclick event and call the function to load the modal.

```js
   $.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/Action/",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (value) {
                $('#ModalContainer').html();
                $('#ModalContainer').html(value);
                $('#Modal').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (value) {}
        });
```